# How to load a single byte from address in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

How can I load a single byte from address? I thought it would be something like this:

```
mov      rax, byte[rdi]
```

Comment: A duplicate with more detailed answers: [Why can't I move directly a byte to a 64 bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22621340)

Answer (score 10):

```
mov al, [rdi]
```

Merge a byte into the low byte of RAX.

---

Or better, avoid a false dependency on the old value of RAX by zero-extending into a 32-bit register (and [thus implicitly to 64 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6)) with [MOVZX](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx):

```
movzx  eax, byte [rdi]       ; most efficient way to load one byte on modern x86
```

Or if you want sign-extension into a wider register, use [MOVSX](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movsx:movsxd).

```
movsx  eax, byte [rdi]    ; sign extend to 32-bit, zero-extend to 64
movsx  rax, byte [rdi]    ; sign extend to 64-bit
```

(On some CPUs, MOVSX is just as efficient as MOVZX, handled right in a load port without even needing an ALU uop.  https://uops.info.  But there are some where MOVZX loads are cheaper than MOVSX, so prefer MOVZX if you don't care about the upper bytes and really just want to avoid partial-register shenanigans.)

---

The MASM equivalent replaces `byte` with `byte ptr`.

A `mov` load doesn't need a size specifier (`al` destination implies `byte` operand-size).   `movzx` always does for a memory source because a 32-bit destination doesn't disambiguate between 8 vs. 16-bit memory sources.

The [AT&T equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317922/what-does-the-movzbl-instruction-do-in-ia-32-att-syntax) is `movzbl (%rdi), %eax` (with movzb specifying that we zero-extend a byte, the l specifying 32-bit destination size.)