# Why MOV AH,1 is not supported in 64 bit mode of intel microprocessor?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

In the book "THE INTEL MICROPROCESSORS" of Barry B. Brey, it is written that

```
MOV AH, 1
```

is not allowed in 64 bit mode, but allowed in 32 bit or 16 bit mode. If `MOV AL, 1` can be allowed in 64 bit mode, what is the problem with `MOV AH, 1` ?

Comment: That book is wrong then.

Comment: "the book of Barry B. Brey" ← what a strange way to refer to a book. Does that book not have a *title* that you could give us?

Comment: @CodyGray edited

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no problem with `mov ah,1`. It runs just fine in X64 mode.

The opcode for it is `b4 01`.

The only time when `mov ah` is not allowed is when the `mov` has a `REX` prefix.

from: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html

> ***In 64-bit mode, r/m8 can not be encoded to access the following byte registers if a REX prefix is used: `AH`, `BH`, `CH`, `DH`.

In that case the high byte registers (`AH`, `BH`, `CH`, and `DH`) are redefined as
`DIL`, `SIL`, `BPL` and `SPL`. But this is only if a REX prefix is present.

Instructions with a REX prefix are:

```
anything with the R8..R15 regs and parts thereof
anything that accesses the new 8 bit regs: DIL, SIL, BPL, SPL
anything that accesses 64 bit registers.
```

Comment: So I can't use any instruction like MOV AH, R10B but I can use instructions like MOV AH, BL and MOV AL, R10B in the 64 bit mode. Am I correct?

Comment: That's correct, @lab11. The only time you cannot use AH, BH, CH, or DH is when you use DIL, SIL, BPL, SPL, R8B, R9B, R10B, R11B, R12B, R13B, R14B, or R15B as the other operand, because all of these require a REX prefix. Just try it; your assembler will tell you if something is wrong!

Comment: @CodyGray: A more important obstacle is that stuff like `movzx r10d, ah` is not encodeable.  Or even `movsx rdi, ah`.  Also, `mov [r10], ah` is not encodeable, since that needs a REX prefix for the base register.  In x86-64, the main use of AH is to save a shift when chopping up RAX into bytes.  (Or on CPUs without partial-reg stalls, to merge bytes into wider integers).  You usually don't need to use AL and AH as separate byte registers just because of register pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Please also note that, according to the Intel optimization manual, the use of 8-bit registers is discouraged for some processors, while for others not. Currently, it is only discouraged for Knights Landing, but in the future, the list of processors where 8-bit and 16-bit instructions would work slower may grow. Intel wrote the following in the manual:

> Instructions that operate on 8-bit or 16-bit registers are not optimized in hardware in the Knights Landing microarchitecture. In general, it is faster to use integer instructions operating on 32-bit or 64-bit general-purpose registers than 8-bit or 16-bit registers.

Although the Knights Landing is not a general-purpose CPU, I anticipate the tendency that on all future processors, probably, in a next major microarchitecture change, namely, since the Icelake microarchitecture, which is the Intel CPU microarchitecture based on the 10nm node that is expected to replace Cannonlake in 2019 - the 8-bit and 16-bit register operation will be slow, and not just write, but the read also (Disclaimer: this anticipation of mine is a pure speculation).

So, back to the `ah` register - you cannot encode, for example, `movzx r8, ah` in 64-bit mode, but you can encode anything with the `ah` register per se, e.g. `mov ah, 1` - because AMD has designed the 64-bit mode in such a way that the old instructions are encoded the same way as in the old 32-bit mode.

Comment: King's landing is **not** a general purpose CPU. It is meant for scientific calculation purposes.

Comment: @Johan - thank you, I have updated my reply to address your issue. Although the Knights Landing is not a general-purpose CPU, I anticipate the tendency that on all future processors, probably, in a next major microarchitecture change, namely, since the Icelake microarchitecture, which is the Intel CPU microarchitecture based on the 10nm node that is expected to replace Cannonlake in 2019 (Disclaimer: this anticipation of mine is a pure speculation) ---  the 8-bit and 16-bit register operation will be slow, and not just write, but the read also.

Comment: If your prediction comes true, is going to be *very* bad news for the `SETcc` instructions, which still *require* 8-bit register operands. 16-bit register operation is already somewhat slow because of the required prefix, but 8-bit isn't really any slower. In fact, it's faster now than it's been in many years because of minimizing the effect of partial register stalls. I don't know what Intel means when they say "not optimized in hardware". I sort of doubt your prediction will come true. KNL is a very unusual microarchitecture for a number of reasons, and I doubt it's going to be mainstreamed.

Comment: @CodyGray - I think this is not related to Knights Landing. As `loop` and many other useful instructions once felt out of favour, so will the 8-bit and 16-bit instructions.

Comment: `loop` was never particularly useful, since it was precisely equivalent to `dec cx`+`jnz Label`. It never really caught on with compilers, and Intel stopped trying to make it fast. It's also part of the x86's CISC legacy, which stopped being fast after x86 converted to RISC internally. I don't think 8-bit and 16-bit instructions are at all comparable to that. Also, like I said, there are *important* instructions that require 8-bit register operands, like `SETcc`, that there just aren't good replacements for. If KNL had introduced `SETcc r32`, then that would be something!

Comment: @CodyGray: Skylake already has slow AH, but still fast AL.  (`movzx edx, ah`: 2c latency.  `movzx edx, al`: 0c latency, eliminated.  `movzx eax, al`: 1c latency, not eliminated because of same register).  I'd be surprised if Intel made AL/R8B/etc. slow in Cannonlake, because lots of real compiler-generated code uses low byte registers.  It's possible though, esp. if they get compiler changes started ahead of time.  Or maybe they will just screw us over and make lots of existing code sub-optimal until people recompile with brand-new compiler versions.

Comment: (Also, `xor eax,eax`/`cmp`/`setcc al` has been fast since P6. 
 Partial-register issues have been an easily-avoidable problem for `setcc` on Intel and AMD for years.  HSW's "free" partial-reg merging isn't needed, because xor-zeroing sets the internal upper-bits-clear flag, which allows reading EAX after writing AL without needing to merge.)

Comment: @CodyGray: Also, according to Agner Fog, KNL still has fast byte ops.  Agner's testing did miss the Skylake AL/AH difference (which affects `add ah, bh` and stuff, too, not just narrow read after full-reg write), though, and the movzx elimination.  Anyway, Agner lists the same performance for all register sizes for most instructions, like `add`.  `crc32 r32, r8` is worse than the others, but Silvermont is the same.  `mul r8` is the same as `mul r32`, both better than `mul r16`, again same as Silvermont.  `SHLD r16,r16` is terrible, but so is `r64`.  Only `shld r32,r32,i` is fast on KNL/Silver.

Comment: @CodyGray and Maxim: My guess is that this paragraph in the Intel manual is an over-simplification of the fact that Silvermont/KNL doesn't rename partial registers separately, so `mov al, 1` has a false dependency on the old value of EAX, even if you never actually read EAX.  Also, the quoted text appears in the "flags usage" section of the KNL chapter.  (fun fact: KNL has flag-merging stalls on `dec / jnz`, so use `sub reg,1` instead.  Guess I'd better go update my avoiding-`inc`-is-only-for-P4 answers!)

Comment: @PeterCordes - in that case, Intel has just probably meant false dependancy on other data left in higher bits of the registers. Intel has already mentioned about it in the manual, in the other places. If it is the case, than at least reading from 8-bit registers should be as fast as before -- as you have pointed out a few days ago.

Comment: @PeterCordes - On the other hand, I think that Intel will still accomodate to modern compilers. Just take the code produced by the latest version of Microsoft Visual Studio C/C++ compiler and what instructions does it put, whether it uses 8-bit registers much or little, etc. Which kind of instructions and sequences Microsoft Compiler uses now - that instructions and sequences will be supported in a fast way by the Intel Processors in a few years, and the rest will become slower. Just my crystal ball tells that ;-)  For example, I've used `loop` much for 80286, but the compilers at that time no