# Address sections of a 32-bit registers

Tags: cpu, cpu-registers

During a lecture about CPU registers. The lecturer told us about 32-bit registers and the sections of such a registers. He told us that there is no way to address the **upper sections** of a register.

This made me wonder what he meant with the **upper sections** of a register. Does he mean the *AH* section or the *dark-blue* section (in this case a EAX register).

[View schematic image of register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJiab.png)

Comment: The `ah` section has a name: `ah`, so it's accessible (e.g. `mov ah, 1`, though in 64-bit [some limitations apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083737/why-mov-ah-1-is-not-supported-in-64-bit-mode-of-intel-microprocessor)) :) The instructor meant the dark-blue section. We call it the "upper" part because bits there are weighted more than the bits in the other part. Just like the first one in 101 weights more (hundreds) than the last one (units).

Comment: @MargaretBloom, great, thanks for your response!! Much appreciated.