# MOVZX with bit-fields

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I have following snippet:

```c
typedef struct {
        unsigned int gender: 1;
        unsigned int age:    7;
        unsigned int uid:    24;
} person;

int 
f(person *p) {
        return p->gender;
}
```

which generates (`gcc` **-O2**):

```
f:
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rdi]           ; this line looks interesting.
        and     eax, 1
        ret
```

## Questions

- If I understand correctly `MOVZX` adds `0`s at the beginning. As you can see in the next line it `AND`s the value with `1`. The question is: does `MOVZX` provide any value here? I mean wouldn't it work with a normal `MOV`? I need only the first **bit** there right?
- I sadly couldn't find a "speed comparison" between `MOV` vs `MOVZX`. Can someone tell me does one perform better than the other (I'm assuming that `MOVZX` is slower, because it has to go and "clear out" the bits. If I'm not wrong)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiler generates costly MOVZX instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491737/compiler-generates-costly-movzx-instruction)  (to be clear, title is wrong, `movzx` isn't actually costly, it's reading from memory that costs something).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't know. Can you maybe explain why is it there in my example? I couldn't understand it from the given link. I found that link before asking this question. However my knowledge is extremely limited in this area. That's why am I asking.

Comment: [This answer (second ranked at time of writing)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43910889/364696) fully answers your question as to why the compiler is using `movzx`; it removes partial register dependencies, so if stuff was left in other parts of `eax` it's not forced to wait on them. If it didn't do that, `and` would have to wait for the other parts of `eax` to "finalize" before it could do its work. `movzx` actually has negative cost; the cost of zero-extension is zero, and if it breaks a dependency, allowing the `and` to run immediately when it otherwise wouldn't, it actually speeds things up.

Comment: `mov` and `movzx` loads are the same speed on modern CPUs.  Zeroing the high bits happens right in the load port, no separate ALU uop needed; https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize/

Comment: @ShadowRanger: `mov  eax, dword ptr [rdi]` would also be legal here, and avoid partial *register* problems.  But that could give you a store-forwarding stall depending on recent stores, so I'd guess GCC is loading the smallest possible chunk that fully contains the bitfield you want.  (And yes, a zero-extending load is generally the best way to do that, and what GCC always chooses, despite costing an extra byte of code-size vs. byte or dword `mov`.)

Comment: After reading the comments and the contents of links multiple times... Now I do understand the concept. Thank you all.

Comment: [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41574531) is also a good answer for why GCC chooses movzx instead of a byte `mov`, in case that's what you were wondering.  For details on its performance, see [Any way to move 2 bytes in 32-bit x86 using MOV without causing a mode switch or cpu stall?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13092829) (the premise of the question is wrong, there's never a "mode switch" and it's not slow on CPUs after P5 Pentium)