# Load only first byte into a register, from a string at a label

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to load only the first byte in a register after data is passed into it
for example if I have the following ASM code

```
global _start
section .data
string db "Hello", 0x00 ; string = Hello
section .text
_start:
mov eax, string ; move "Hello" into eax (just to store it for now)
```

this is where I am stuck, I want to ONLY store "H" into eax, so for instance if I moved "H" into EAX, then moved eax into edx so EDX = "H", I could do:

```
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, edx ; This is so I can store "H" in ecx
mov edx, 12 ; 12 is longer than the string, however, I am just using this to test, as it should only output "H", rather than anything else, the reason for this is later I want to use "H" in a  cmp statement
int 0x80 ; execute the system call
```

Now I have also tried using al, ex: `mov [edx], al` after moving string into eax, but this still outputs the full string, if a working example can be provided for this, that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `mov [edx], al` stores the byte in AL into the memory location pointed at by EDX. This is way off.

Comment: Note that the write system call expects a pointer to a buffer.  It will not do what you expect with a character loaded into a register.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev If I do `global _start
section .data
        string db "testing", 0x00
section .text
        _start:
        xor eax, eax
        mov eax, string
        mov [edx], al
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, edx
        mov edx, 12
        int 0x80
        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 0x80
` It returns a segfault, any ideas?

Comment: Oy my eyes. Next time edit the question. Anyway, in the `mov [edx],al` you try to write a byte into the memory location that EDX points to. EDX contains garbage. That's your segfault.

Comment: The opposite question, loading a byte, is [How to load a single byte from address in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20727379) (Seva's answer here seems to be answering that.)

Answer (score 3):

To move the first byte of the string into `al` (which is the lowest byte of `eax`), use

```
mov al, [string]
```

If you want to move the byte into the low byte of eax *and zero out the rest of eax*, you can do

```
movzx eax, byte [string]
```

But you don't have to use EAX for that. You can load the byte into whatever register you want. Specifically EAX is probably a bad choice, since `int 80h` expects the syscall number there. It's not immediately obvious from the pasted code what are you trying to do with that "H" character afterwards...

---

If you are going to print the string to the console using the `write` syscall (#4) with the `stdout` file descriptor (1), which sounds like the natural thing to do, then, like fuz said, you don't need to load the contents of the string into any registers; the syscall expects the address of the string rather than its contents. To the best of my knowledge, there's no single character output in Linux.

---

In general, you seem to be confused between the address of the string and the contents on the string.

Comment: The question is tagged #nasm so the exact syntax would be `movzx eax, byte [string]` (no `ptr` keyword).

Comment: Sorry, MASM reflexes. Fixed.