# MOVZBQ equivalent in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, att

---

Background:

I have been learning x86_64 assembly using NASM on a Linux system and was writing a subroutine for `strlen(const char *str)`

I wanted to copy one byte starting from a pointer stored in `rax` and comparing it to `0` to find the end of the string, but when I used `mov rbx, [rax]` I didn't get the results I wanted which I later learned to be a wrong approach as `rbx` is quadword length and `mov` will copy 8 bytes at a time. The suggested solution was to use `bl` instead which did work.

I also found in AT&T syntax the `movzbq` mnemonic to copy one byte and zero extend it to a quadword, which in my newbie eyes looked as a neater more accurate representation of the intended instruction as I am not only moving to `bl` but also erasing the remaining 7 bytes.

---

Question:

Is there an equivalent to `movzbq` and other AT&T `mov` variants in NASM?

Which is a better code practice, `movzbq rbx, [address]` or `mov bl, [address]`?

---

Thank you,

Comment: Near duplicate of [How to load a single byte from address in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20727379), except for the part about how AT&T syntax works.  The top of that answer suggests the less-useful way, mov into a byte reg, but the rest of the answer suggests the standard way, zero-extend into the full register.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for the referral.
I am new to asking questions here on stackoverflow, is there an easy way to find duplicates before posting or is it up to community members to notice them?

Comment: Usually with google, e.g. `site:stackoverflow.com x86-64 load byte` (or maybe "zero extend byte", but I didn't try that").  Or "translate AT&T to Intel", e.g. assemble with GAS, disassemble with objconv into NASM syntax, or with `objdump -drwC -Mintel`).  But it's not generally expected that newbies will come up with the right search terms if they were thinking about a problem from a different direction or not aware of standard terminology.  I already knew of the existence of that question (since I wrote half the answer) so it comes up high in my google searches, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Intel syntax, the size of memory operands is indicated by a prefix on the operand.  So you would write `movzx rbx, byte [address]`.

However, writes to 32-bit registers automatically zero-extend into the 64-bit register.  So `movzx ebx, byte [address]` is equivalent and saves one byte of code (no REX prefix needed).

Generally `movzx ebx, byte [address]` is preferable to `mov bl, [address]` because it overwrites the entire register.  Writing to the byte-sized register can have a minor performance penalty in some cases, see [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers/41574531#41574531) for details.  Though `mov bl, [address]` is fewer bytes of code, which may be worth the tradeoff if you need to optimize for size.