# string_cmp in inline assembly

Tags: assembly, inline-assembly

I am trying to write the string_cmp function in assembly where you try to compare if two strings are the same.

int string_cmp(const char* str1, char* str2) {
int res;

```
// Your inline assembly code goes here. Note that volatile keyword ensure that the assembly code will not be moved around by the compiler
asm volatile (
    "loop1:"
        "mov (%[s1]), %%rsi\n"   // Move the source address to rsi
        "mov (%[s2]), %%rdx\n" //I wanted a name register but i couldnt initialsied rdx for some reason and %0 cannot be tested
        "inc %[s1]\n"
        "inc %[s2]\n" //check for end of a string then comp last char
        "test %%rsi, %%rdx\n"
        "jl neg\n"
        "jg pos\n"
        "cmp $0, %%rsi\n"
        "jne loop1\n"
        "je zero\n"

    "pos:"
        "mov $1, %%eax\n"
        "jmp fin\n"

    "zero:"
        "mov $0, %%eax\n"
        "jmp fin\n"

    "neg:"
        "mov $0xFFFFFFFF, %%eax\n"
        "jmp fin\n"

    "fin:"




    // Continue with the string copy using appropriate instructions
: "=a" (res)
: [s1] "r" (str1), [s2] "r" (str1) //need to initiate variables somewhere
: "%rsi"  // Use these as needed //clobbbered
);
return res;
```

}

This is my implementation thus far, so I move the pointer of the strings into registers check if they are the different using test then loop until i reach a null character for the one of the strings.

This however always return a 1 even if the strings are equal, is it due to the jg which always goes through seeing as most of the time the zero and sign bit are ?

Is there a different conditional I could use so the comparison works properly so it jumps to 1 when the value of the left parameter is greater?

the lines below are I am trying to put the results in a register and return those.
I also added a jmp after the conditional branching however this did not stop the string from being constantly just the value 1 despite comparing a word to an empty string and comparing a string to an empty word (these should be different).
Thank you very much.

Comment: You're missing a `"memory"` clobber; see [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56432259) .  Also, `%1` is the `[s1]` pointer input; GCC inline asm numbers from `0`.  And you're doing 8-byte loads / compares, not single bytes.  Use `movzbl`: [How to load a single byte from address in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20727379)  . Also, you're using `test` to bitwise-AND them together, not `cmp %al, (%[s2])` or something.  Single-step your code in a debugger (in disassembly mode) and look at register values.

Comment: I'd also point out that you are modifying an input parameter.  The gcc [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#InputOperands) have a pretty clear **Warning** about this: *Do not modify the contents of input-only operands.* and *The compiler assumes that on exit from the asm statement these operands contain the same values as they had before executing the statement.*  While you might "get away with it," breaking the rules is always a risky plan.

Comment: I strongly recommend not using inline assembly for learning.  It is not a good tool for that purpose and will introduce all sorts of tricky problems.  Just write assembly code in assembly source files.  Do not use inline assembly.

Comment: @fuz While I agree with you about using inline asm for learning (I usually point to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm)), in this case we're probably talking to a student.  Not much he's going to be able to do about what assignments the teacher gives.

Answer (score -1):

If you go to `zero:` there's nothing stopping the CPU from executing the next two `mov`s afterwards as well. So you'll always end up with 1. Add an extra label at the end and make an unconditional jump to that after you set the res value.

Something like:

```
    "zero:"
        "mov $0, %1\n"
        "jmp finish\n"
    "neg:"
        "mov $0xFFFFFFFF, %1\n"
        "jmp finish\n"
    "pos:"
        "mov $1, %1\n"
    "finish:"
```

Comment: This doesnt stop the code from going through for some reason

Comment: @shinny.dogma: Have you single-stepped it with a debugger?  Your previous code did have this bug if it ever jumped to one of the other labels.  It *also* has other critical bugs pointed out in comments.  The ones you didn't didn't fix include always jumping to `pos:` because the bitwise AND between two 8-**byte** load results was probably always non-zero and non-negative.  (So `test` clears ZF, and it's a bitwise AND so it always clears OF.  SF is set based on the high bits of 64-bit RSI & RDX, from `str1[7] & str2[7]`.  If either string is longer than 8 bytes and ASCII, MSB = 0 so SF=0.)

Comment: @shinny.dogma: You probably want `cmp %%dl, %%sil`, or use zero-extending byte loads so you can `cmp %%edx, %%esi`.  [How to load a single byte from address in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20727379)