# Why does GCC use movzbl again to zero-extend a register that's already zero-extended?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, x86-64, cpu-architecture

I am wondering why this code:

```
size_t hash_word(const char* c, size_t size) {
    size_t hash = uchar(c[0]);
    hash ^= uchar(c[size - 1]);
    hash ^= uchar(c[size - 2]);
    return hash;
}
```

When compiled:

```
    movzbl  -1(%rcx,%rdx), %eax
    xorb    -2(%rcx,%rdx), %al
    xorb    (%rcx), %al
    movzbl  %al, %eax            <-
    ret
```

Results in that second movzbl line.

I converted to asm with `g++ -Wall -O3 -S file.cpp`

The way I understand it, all the upper bits of %eax should already be set to zero from the first movzbl. Then the following two xorb's shouldn't modify any of the upper bits as it only touches the bits in %al. So why is an additional instruction needed at all? Shouldn't it be done after the first three?

Comment: Yeah, missed optimisation opportunity, looks like.  It does happen, no compiler is perfect.

Answer (score 7):

P6-family CPUs would have a partial-register stall when the caller read RAX after `xorb` wrote AL.

But on Sandybridge, an RMW on a low-byte register is an RMW on the full register, not renaming it separately from the full reg like `mov mem, %al` would.  And on Ivy Bridge or Haswell, renaming of low-byte registers separate from the full reg was dropped entirely (keeping only high-byte renaming like for AH/BH/CH/DH since that's still sufficient to make AL and AH independent.)  So even `mov mem, %al` is a load + micro-fused ALU uop to merge a low byte on modern Intel P-cores, and everything else.  Partial-register renaming was never a thing on any other microarchitecture family, like P4, Silvermont, or any AMD.

- [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers)
- [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to)

---

The default `-mtune=generic` shouldn't care much if at all about Nehalem and earlier.  And GCC/Clang nightly builds still use `movzbl` (aka Intel `movzx`) with `-mtune=skylake`, `-march=skylake`, or `-mtune=znver1` ([**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:61,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:61,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:61,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:61,startLineNumber:7),source:%27//%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0Aunsigned+long+hash_word(const+unsigned+char*+c,+unsigned+long+size)+%7B%0A++++unsigned+long+hash+%3D+c%5B0%5D%3B%0A++++hash+%5E%3D+c%5Bsize+-+1%5D%3B%0A++++hash+%5E%3D+c%5Bsize+-+2%5D%3B%0A++++//return+hash+%3C+0x100%3B++//+they+know+this+is+always+true%0A++++return+hash%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:38.56619814681563,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-mtune%3Dgoldmont%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:28.09574666652363,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-Wall+-mtune%3Dznver1%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)), so presumably this code-gen choice is baked in, not a matter of updating `tune=generic` settings.

Perhaps historically *because* of how P6 worked, and nobody's bothered to change it now that CPUs are different.  That kind of thing is not rare.  Or perhaps because they don't know how to do this optimization without making mistakes like creating false dependencies by writing only the low 8 bits of a register in some other cases.

GCC and clang do know that `hash < 0x100` is a constant `1`, so they do have sufficient value-range tracking to know that the value is already a zero-extended byte, if they wanted to look for that.

---

**You can report this on [GCC's bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) with the missed-optimization keyword, and also on Clang's issue tracker, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues**

Use `unsigned char` in your minimal example so you don't have to define `uchar`, like the Godbolt link in this answer.  Feel free to quote anything I've written in your compiler bug report, and link this Q&A.

---

> Shouldn't it be done after the first three?

You mean do the first load with `movb -1(%rcx,%rdx), %al`?  That would be worse, with a false dependency on RAX.  MOVZX is [generally the most efficient way to load a byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727379/how-to-load-a-single-byte-from-address-in-assembly), unless you're optimizing for code-size.  And in this case we need zero-extension later, so by far the best choice is to simply drop the `movzbl %al, %eax` and keep everything else the same.  Maybe that's what you meant, the the function should be done, ready to return, after the first three.

RISC ISAs *only* have zero-extend or sign-extend loads, not ones that merge a byte into the old value, because it makes the destination write-only.  `mov mem, %al` is the weird thing that only x86 has.

---

BTW, if you *do* need to zero-extend after some operations, within the same register is the worst choice, but that's what GCC and Clang both do.  They don't seem to optimize for zero-latency `movzx` in Intel since Haswell or IvB.  (Perhaps recent AMD, I forget?)  *[Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all)*

If you were tuning for a mix of modern Intel and P6-family (by including the `movzx` at the end) you could make it less bad for modern Intel this way:

```
    movzbl  -1(%rcx,%rdx), %r8d
    xorb    -2(%rcx,%rdx), %r8b
    xorb    (%rcx), %r8b
    movzbl  %r8b, %eax   # avoid same-register if we keep this for P6's benefit
    ret
```

That costs extra code-size for REX prefixes because the Windows x64 calling convention didn't leave any call-clobbered registers free which have a low-byte part without REX prefixes, other than RAX.

If optimizing purely for P6-family, yes you'd start with a `movb` load into `AL`.

Comment: "If you were tuning for a mix of modern Intel and P6-family" Isn't the P6 32-bit only?

Comment: @ecm: The P6 **family** of microarchitectures include P6 through Nehalem.  Core 2 and Nehalem being the ones that support x86-64.  (Sandybridge is generally considered a significant enough change to be a new family, e.g. with a PRF and a uop cache.  https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/).  Also, the same points would apply if this was 32-bit code that could run on all members of the P6 family and modern CPUs.